# Fglrx doesn't load, system using mesa

Tags: fglrx, mesa

I installed fglrx from Ubuntu repo, yet it doesn't work, system loads with Mesa anyway.

Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialize it after installing? Is your card supported in fglrx (you may need updates-fglrx instead)?

## Steps:

**For ATI Graphics:**

Step #1 = Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

[or you can use fglrx if you need]

Step #2 = Type in terminal:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Step #3 = Type in terminal:

```
sudo reboot
```

Step #4 = Type in terminal:

```
sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial
```

Step #5 = Type in terminal:

```
sudo reboot
```

**For AMD Graphics:**

Step #1 = Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

[or you can use fglrx if you need]

Step #2 = Type in terminal:

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

Step #3 = Type in terminal:

```
sudo reboot
```

Step #4 = Type in terminal:

```
sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial
```

Step #5 = Type in terminal:

```
sudo reboot
```

## Notes:

Note #1 = In my experience the catalyst control center (admin) shortcut doesn't work, you can get around that by using "gksu amdcccle" instead.